# Generating normal distribution

Tags: java, math, statistics, normal-distribution

Question - Assume the sleeping barber problem but here with M barbers instead of 1 barber. Now if the barbers arrive with a mean of Mc and standard deviation SDc.And the barber services customers with mean Mh and standard deviation SDh.

How do I take the input to this problem? Assuming it to follow a normal distribution, and taking inputs of M(barbers), N(customers), Mc,SDc, Mh, SDh. How do I approach the problem in Java?

Should I generate random intervals?

Comment: check Wikipedia: [6 Computational methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Computational_methods)

Comment: I added some examples and a question/recommendation to my answer.

Comment: In such cases arrivals are usually modelled closely by a Poisson process (exponentially distributed inter-arrival times), No idea what a reasonable distribution of service time look like. Whatever distribution(s) you select, there must be Java classes (for simulation?) that give random numbers with the specified distribution. *Don't roll your own*, it's not easy to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [nextGaussian() method in the Random class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian--). The nextGaussian() function will draw samples from a normal distribution with mean 0 and std-deviation 1, so if you want, for example, a mean of 1 hour and std-deviation of 15 minutes you'll need to call it as nextGaussian()*15+60.

From the docs:

> nextGaussian() Returns the next pseudorandom, Gaussian ("normally")
>   distributed double value with mean 0.0 and standard deviation 1.0 from
>   this random number generator's sequence.

See this example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomDemo {
   public static void main( String args[] ) {

      // create random object
      Random randomno = new Random();

      // check next Gaussian value 
      for (int i =0; i<10;i++){
      System.out.println("Next Gaussian value: " + randomno.nextGaussian());
      }
   }      
}
```

compile and run the above program, this will produce the following result.

```
$javac RandomDemo.java
Next Gaussian value: -0.7751137555238873
Next Gaussian value: -0.7533576941233361
Next Gaussian value: 0.20737101421286988
Next Gaussian value: 1.2519939959392383
Next Gaussian value: -0.43613074051716394
Next Gaussian value: -0.7432668748818407
Next Gaussian value: 0.6821771863764128
Next Gaussian value: -1.7738232532706042
Next Gaussian value: -0.5974045649946896
Next Gaussian value: 0.5841939243690774
```

My question is: Are you sure you need a normal distribution? Normally you'd expect interarrival times to have an [exponential distribution](https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/weber/decs-430/Notes%20on%20the%20Poisson%20and%20exponential%20distributions.pdf).